# Clockwise or anticlockwise edges in a polygon

Tags: geometry

Suppose a polygon with $n$ vertices is given $(V_1,V_2,... V_n)$.
If the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the each vertex of the polygon are given, then how can we find that the vertices $V_1,V_2,V_3$... $V_n$ are in clockwise or anticlockwise fashion? - that is, I need to find that if we are moving from $V_1,V_2,\dots V_n$, we are in clockwise or anticlockwise direction.

What I tried :
I found the center of the polygon and took the origin of the coordinate system at the center, and then calculated the angle between the $x$ axis and the vertex.

Problem :
Two vertices may be at same angle.

I need some solution which can be implemented in computer logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need is at [this Wolfram Mathworld link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html). Just compute the area using the expression given there. If the result is positive, the points are anticlockwise; if the result is negative, the points are clockwise.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/

> Subject 2.07: How do I find the orientation of a simple polygon?
>
> Compute the signed area (Subject 2.01).  The orientation is 
>       counter-clockwise if this area is positive.
>
> A slightly faster method is based on the observation that it isn't
>       necessary to compute the area.  Find the lowest vertex (or, if 
>       there is more than one vertex with the same lowest coordinate, 
>       the rightmost of those vertices) and then take the cross product 
>       of the edges fore and aft of it.  Both methods are O(n) for n vertices, 
>       but it does seem a waste to add up the total area when a single cross
>       product (of just the right edges) suffices.  Code for this is
>       available at http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/Code/polyorient.C (2K).
>
> The reason that the lowest, rightmost (or any other such extreme) point
>       works is that the internal angle at this vertex is necessarily convex, 
>       strictly less than pi (even if there are several equally-lowest points).